# 4 imageViews in the center like 2 lines * 2 rows for all devices

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, row, line

i'm trying to put 4 imageViews like they was in 2 lines * 2 rows:
[image]

I did this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/accueil">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/font"
        android:src="@drawable/fond_menu"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/topLogo"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_bleu_petit"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/topText"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/topLogo"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:width="260dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/firstBlock"
                android:src="@drawable/encart_offres"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/topText"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="150dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/secondBlock"
                android:src="@drawable/encart_contact"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/topText"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/thirdBlock"
                android:src="@drawable/encart_actualites"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstBlock"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fourthBlock"
                android:src="@drawable/encart_mentions"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/secondBlock"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/formulaire"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fourthBlock"
                android:background="@drawable/bouton_formulaire"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bottomText"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#626262"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:width="270dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/formulaire" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But with different Device the imageViews are stick between them or are overlap. I think i have to use lines and rows, but i don't know how to di it.

Comment: @hrskrs i don't understand what you trying to do

Comment: I am trying to help you. Where those Texts will be aligned. Do you just want to place 4 images like in the picture you have provided? Or you also need those Texts to include somewhere

Comment: @hrskrs the text dont have to move, i juste want to place the 4 imageViews correctely, your solution don't gonna put the 4 blocks in the center, i want a solution like a grid, and applicable for all devices

Comment: Yeah but where does those text will be added, please draw also where the text will be placed so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use TableLayout like this?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scroll">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/topLogo1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_bleu_petit"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/topLogo2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_bleu_petit"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/topLogo3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_bleu_petit"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/topLogo4"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_bleu_petit"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I hope this can fit your question.

Comment: How to add auto margins or auto centering by device

Comment: I want to center horizontaly the two block but i cant

Comment: it can be set in java using some calculations, such as knowing the height and width of the device, then set margin with respect to the device's height and width

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/font"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```