# Formatting 4 ImageViews in storyboard for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, constraints, uistoryboard

I'm new to iOS development, and I'm trying to make one of my views have something like this: [4 imageViews in the center like 2 lines * 2 rows for all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642293/4-imageviews-in-the-center-like-2-lines-2-rows-for-all-devices), except for iOS, and with one line of text on top. (4 images, with 2 images per row, and 2 rows).

I'm about to rip my hair out trying to get the 4 boxes to position correctly. I've been looking at several examples, but they always end up just being at least a little off or just completely overlapping each other.

Could someone explain the simplest / best-practice way to position the 4 imageViews (2 per row) so that they won't overlap and keep the same aspect ratio for all layouts (size can change, as long as the aspect ratio of the image remains the same)? This alignment constraint stuff seems to be a lot more complicated than the Android layouts that I was familiar with. But maybe it's simpler than I think?

Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `UIStackView` to accomplish this.

**Step 1:** Drag out 2 `UIImageViews` onto your storyboard.

**Step 2:** Line them up side-by-side so the blue guidelines go through the vertical center of them

**Step 3:** Click each Image, then click the StackView button at the bottom of the storyboard window. Make sure the resultant stack is a **HORIZONTAL** stack.

**Step 4:** Highlight the stack, then go to attributes inspector. Set alignment to **Fill**, distribution: **Equally**, spacing to 8 or whatever you want.

**Step 5-8** = repeat 1-4 for the bottom row of images.

**Step 9:** highlight your 2 `UIStackViews`, make them into a **VERTICAL** stack. Same deal on the attributes inspector--alignment **fill**, distribution **equally**, spacing to 8 or whatever you want.

**Step 10:** Highlight the `UIStackView` at the top of document outline , click the Pin button (the "tie-fighter" looking thingie) at the bottom of the interface builder screen and pin to the sides of the view. You probably want to do 0 on the sides and standard value on the top and bottom.

Questions? See this--> http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Answer (score 2):

1. Pin all widths/heights equally
2. Pin horizontal spacing and vertical spacing between your views
3. Pin each view to the sides of the superview it touches
4. Pin aspect ratio of one imageView
5. Profit.